# MFS Agile Process Template Work Items

Tags: tfs, development-process

Where can I find a practical example on how to use Bug, Risk, Scenario, Task and Quality of Service Requirement work items?

On MSDN documentation I found this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668962.aspx but it is not enough for me to deeply understand when to use one or the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single prescriptive way of using the work items. You have to adjust this to your own process and your own needs and primarily decide what you want to get out of TFS a this particular process template.

A good place to start might be the literature on agile methodology, for example:

- [User Stories Applied: For Agile Software Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321205685)
- [Succeeding with Agile: Software Development Using Scrum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321579364)

Comment: @mfloryan: You are probably right but I need a trivial real-world example/tutorial on how to use them. Afterward I will adjust them to our own process. The sentence: "Represents a single path of user interaction through the system." tells really a little to me. What is the purpose of this 'single path' for example? Describe a new feature?

Comment: Added two books with might be a good reference. I really don't think this is specific to TFS - it is more about the agile process.

Comment: @myfloryan: I gave a look to the Table of Contents of the books you provided but none of the two mentions the work items I am interested in. Only the second one explains User Stories that it is something I need to learn as well. Thanks.